# Java Command Pattern prepopulate list of Invoker class

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern, command-pattern, ooad

I have number of classes that parses String. These Strings are sent by LAS (Laboratory Automation System) machines after performing sample's tests and then parser classes are responsible to parse them and extract results from String.

As every machine sends String in different formats, so can't have single and generic String parser. The class responsible to get String from machine is called `Controller`. Controller knows all the information of machine and is generic. There is only one `Controller` and multiple parser.

Now the **problem** is how `Controller` will know which parser to invoke for data extraction.

I have implemented [Command Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/command_pattern.htm) but according to the example, `private List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();` this list needs to be populated before `invoke()` is called out.

So, it sense that I need to create object of all Parser classes and add them in list in order to know which Parser should be invoked.

Here is my code:

**Abstract Parser:**

```
public abstract class Parser {

private final String resultString;
private final String machineId;

  protected Parser(final String result, final String machineId){
    resultString = result;
    this.machineId = machineId;
  }

  /**
   * This method's implementation will parse the output string. The method    @see setResultString(String) must be called before parsing. 
   */
  abstract void  Parse();

  protected String getResultString(){
     return this.resultString;
  }

  protected String getMachineId(){
     return this.machineId;
  }
}
```

**Concrete Parser:**

*1. COBASParser*

```
public class COBASParser extends Parser{

  public COBASParser(final String resultString, final String machineId){
     super(resultString, machineId);
  }

@Override
 void Parse() {
     System.out.println("This is COBAS's Parse() method");
     System.out.println("ResultString:: "+getResultString());
  }

}
```

*2. E170Parser*

```
public class E170Parser extends Parser {

  public E170Parser(final String resultString, final String machineId) {
     super(resultString, machineId);
  }

  @Override
  void Parse() {
     System.out.println("This is E170Parser's Parse() method");
     System.out.println("ResultString:: "+getResultString());
  }
}
```

**Invoker Class:**

```
public class ParserInvoker {

  private static ParserInvoker me;
  private List<Parser> parsersList;

  private ParserInvoker() {
     parsersList = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void addParser(Parser parser) {
     parsersList.add(parser);
  }

/**
 * Invokes concrete class parser.
 * @param machineId 
 */
 public void invoke(final String machineId) {
      for (Parser p : parsersList) {
         if (p.getMachineId().equals(machineId)) {
             p.Parse();
         }
      }
 }
 public static synchronized ParserInvoker getInvoker() {
     if (me == null) {
         me = new ParserInvoker();
      }
      return me;
 }
}
```

What should I do? Should I adopt any other pattern (Abstract Factory Pattern) or I haven't implemented the Pattern correct?

Here is my `Controller`

```
class LASController{

   void OnDataRecieve(String resultString, String machineId){
     // Call Parser here
   }

}
```

Comment: For working code, codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place. We dont discuss code here, we just help when its broken ;-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for Code Review SE!

Comment: It is not about code, it is about approach :-), I need assistance in may approach towards problem solving.

Comment: And for that, I think it is too broad.

Comment: We can narrow down if you can point out the edit

Answer (score 0):

You have done the first 4 steps of `command pattern`, this is the last step:

```
class LASController{

   void OnDataRecieve(String resultString, String machineId){
     // Call Parser here
       Parser p1 = new COBASParser(resultString1, machineId1);
       Parser p2 = new E170Parser(resultString2, machineId2);
       ParserInvoker.getInvoker().addParser(p1);
       ParserInvoker.getInvoker().addParser(p2);
       // invoke parser
       ParserInvoker.getInvoker().invoke(machineId);
   }
}
```

This pattern makes use of Java `polymorphic` mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Dave, what if I have 50 parsers? Will I create 50 objects? How to use Abstract Factory Pattern here?